# como deserealizar un json con barras diagonales

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo el sigueinte json:

> "{\r\n  \"access_token\": \"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyaWNoYXJkLnZpcXVlekBzb2Z0bGFuZC5jciIsImp0aSI6IjBmOWFkYzJlLTExNmYtNDk0Ni1iZmFjLWFhYmMyZWVkZGZhNSIsImlhdCI6MTU1ODYzNDg2MSwibmJmIjoxNTU4NjM0OTM0LCJleHAiOjE1NTg2Mzg1MzQsImlzcyI6Ik1vYmlsZUFwaSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9zb2Z0bGFuZGNsb3Vkc3luYy5henVyZXdlYnNpdGVzLm5ldCJ9.XuFKNyr5xZFqJvfZBn7XSc0iLuaXzZWrZJ6TvGrxbo8\",\r\n  \"expires_in\": 3600\r\n}"

Intento deserealizarlo asi:

```
await Task.Run(()=> {

                Response1 = Client1.Execute(Request1) ;

                JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(Response1.Content);

                var Result = from token in jsonObject.Properties()
                             select new TokenEstructura()
                             {
                                 AccesToken = token.Value["acces_token"].ToString(),
                                 ExpiresIn=Int32.Parse(token.Value["expires_in"].ToString())
                             };

                foreach (var token in Result)
                {
                    responseResult = token.AccesToken;
                }

            });
```

Pero me devuelve un error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: String. Path '', line 1, position 412

Comment: que objeto es `Response1` ?  porque quizas ese `Content` no tenga un string correcto

Comment: hace un replace de "\" por "" y "\r\n" por "" tambien. Porque estas teniendo un problema de formato. Con esto ya deberias poder parsearlo como un json valido

Comment: @LeandroTuttini  Es de tipo IRestResponse

Comment: Gracias ya lo solucione y si era algo con las barras

Comment: Era simplemente agregarle esto al header  Request1.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");

Comment: Content es un string ? si lo asignas a un textbox o quizas si lo persistes en un archivo, visualizas esos \r\n y demas \" ?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza este using:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
   public void GetSerializado()
   {
       var obj = "{\r\n \"access_token\": \"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyaWNoYXJkLnZpcXVlekBzb2Z0bGFuZC5jciIsImp0aSI6IjBmOWFkYzJlLTExNmYtNDk0Ni1iZmFjLWFhYmMyZWVkZGZhNSIsImlhdCI6MTU1ODYzNDg2MSwibmJmIjoxNTU4NjM0OTM0LCJleHAiOjE1NTg2Mzg1MzQsImlzcyI6Ik1vYmlsZUFwaSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9zb2Z0bGFuZGNsb3Vkc3luYy5henVyZXdlYnNpdGVzLm5ldCJ9.XuFKNyr5xZFqJvfZBn7XSc0iLuaXzZWrZJ6TvGrxbo8\",\r\n \"expires_in\": 3600\r\n}";
       var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(obj, typeof(Token));
   }
```

Cuando realices una serialización/deserialización utiliza una estructura de referencia, en este caso una clase que llamé token ya que por la apariencia de tu mensaje original es un token de una API:

```
    public class Token
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public long expires_in { get; set; }
    }
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que estas implementando funciona perfecto.

Realice una prueba usando la libreria de `Newtonsoft.Json` para deserializar el json con los mismos caracteres que mencionas en el ejemplo y el parse aplica sin problemas

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{\r\n \"access_token\": \"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJyaWNoYXJkLnZpcXVlekBzb2Z0bGFuZC5jciIsImp0aSI6IjBmOWFkYzJlLTExNmYtNDk0Ni1iZmFjLWFhYmMyZWVkZGZhNSIsImlhdCI6MTU1ODYzNDg2MSwibmJmIjoxNTU4NjM0OTM0LCJleHAiOjE1NTg2Mzg1MzQsImlzcyI6Ik1vYmlsZUFwaSIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9zb2Z0bGFuZGNsb3Vkc3luYy5henVyZXdlYnNpdGVzLm5ldCJ9.XuFKNyr5xZFqJvfZBn7XSc0iLuaXzZWrZJ6TvGrxbo8\",\r\n \"expires_in\": 3600\r\n}";

        Token token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(token.access_token);
        Console.WriteLine(token.expires_in);

    }
}
```

Para eso defines la clase

```
public class Token
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public long expires_in { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: porque un voto negativo? al menos explique la razon asi puedo mejorar la explicacion. No voten solo por votar, asi no se mejora. Quien plantea la pregunta esta usando Newtonsoft.Json, la respuesta debia ser usando esa misma libreria no cambiando a otra

Comment: Los invivibles que en lugar de ayudar andan jodiendo la vida con votos y correcciones necias.